# Micro-Voltage Reference

Tags: amplifier, voltage-reference, calibration

I need a micro-Voltage reference to calibrate my micro-Volt amplifier. The ICs only go down to 200mV, fixed.

So how should I go about this? Use the lowest I could find, then use a Voltage Divider to go down the micro range? Doesn't seem to be much of a problem since said amplifier have a high Input Impedance.

Or, use an adjustable Voltage Reference that are usually settable using resistors as well (assuming it can be set to micro-Volt).

Or, combination?

We can assume that the resistors are very high precision and low noise.

Comment: Find the best precision regular possible, then pot down making sure the bottom resistor is a low value to minimise error due to input current. Use the high precision resistors.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use a voltage divider. For example, you can get 10 ohm 0.1% resistors for < $1. Then you can divide down (say) a 2.5V reference to 25mV or whatever you need. It's possible to use less than 10 ohms for the low side of the divider, but then you would probably need to use four wire Kelvin connections to the lower value resistor and the output would not be ground referenced and the reference  have to deliver too much current.

You can parallel a precise resistor with a similar (or perhaps lower precision) resistor to get a precise ratio. For example, to get 25mV from a 2.5V reference you could use 10 ohms 0.1% (low side) and 1K 0.1% in parallel with 100K 1% (high side), to get 25mV +/-0.2%.

For uV accuracy, take care that the layout and thermal conditions are well controlled. Just a 10m ohm resistance in series with the 10 ohm 0.1% will completely destroy the accuracy and that's only about 1/2" of relatively wide 0.05" 0.5oz copper. Similarly, keep the resistors away from any heat sources and try to keep them shielded from air currents (more because of thermal EMFs than because of the temperature coefficient of the resistors).

The resistor noise should not be much more than the theoretical minimum Johnson-Nyquist noise - about 90nV RMS over a 50kHz bandwidth for a 10 ohm resistor.

In addition to input impedance, which you say is relatively high, pay some attention to bias current. It's possible to have a high input impedance amplifier with a relatively high bias current, since the bias current may be relatively constant and impedance is an AC characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, a voltage divider would be the simplest way.  Just be sure that the divider resistor you are attaching to the input of the amp is at least 10x smaller than the input impedance of the amp.  If that doesn't work out, you can have the divider feed an op amp set up as a voltage follower to buffer the divider output.  If the amp impedance is a constant, you can also factor that into calculating the voltage divider.

Comment: We should mention that buffering uV without adding a lot of noise and offset voltage requires a very special amplifer- and few actually spec the output noise at low gain- most are spec'd for input-referred noise at high gain. The 10:1 is okay if 10% error is acceptable, if 0.1% error due to loading is sought then we need 100x better than that (so 10K minimum input impedance for 10 ohms).